# How to return NAs for missing combinations while using group by in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this

```
library(data.table)    
tt1 <- structure(list(start = c(3, 4, 4, 4, 22, 4, 16), 
                      end = c(5, 40,40, 40, 25, 40, 18), 
                      u = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
                      duration = c(2, 36, 36, 36, 3, 36, 2), 
                      i.start = c(3, 3, 29, 20, 20, 14, 14), 
                      i.end = c(5, 5, 31, 22, 22, 16, 16), 
                      q = c(7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 10L), 
                      i.duration = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA,-7L),
                 class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
                 .Names = c("start", "end", "u", "duration", "i.start", "i.end", "q", "i.duration"))

setDT(tt1)
> tt1
   start end u duration i.start i.end  q i.duration
1:     3   5 1        2       3     5  7          2
2:     4  40 2       36       3     5  7          2
3:     4  40 2       36      29    31  8          2
4:     4  40 2       36      20    22  9          2
5:    22  25 3        3      20    22  1          2
6:     4  40 2       36      14    16 10          2
7:    16  18 4        2      14    16 10          2
```

I would like to filter records whose "duration" <=2 and group elements by each combination of (i.start,i.end). I was able to do this by,

```
> tt1[duration<=2, mean(duration), by =c("i.start","i.end"),nomatch=NA]
   i.start i.end V1
1:       3     5  2
2:      14    16  2
```

However, I would also like NA's to be returned for the (i.start,i.end) groups whose duration>2 along with the previous result.

```
   i.start i.end V1
1:       3     5  2
2:      14    16  2
3:      29    31  NA
4:      20    22  NA
```

How can this be done?

Comment: fyi:  `tt[duration<=2, mean(duration), by =c("i.start","i.end")]` is not reproducible. I guess you mean `tt1`but it still returns error

Comment: @BigDataScientist  Sorry. Yes, It should work with tt1, I have corrected that now. What error are you getting?

Comment: `Error in `[.data.frame`(tt1, i.duration <= 2, mean(i.duration), by = c("i.start",  : 
  unused argument (by = c("i.start", "i.end"))` Maybe, i dont have a relevant package loaded. But dont bother about me, i just wanted to point that maybe more answers come if it is reproducible fast :)

Comment: You keep forgetting to convert to `data.table` in your MWEs. Regarding your question, you could do `tt1[, mean(duration[duration<=2]), by =c("i.start","i.end")]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I keep assuming that dput() will save the object with its class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep all the groups then you probably will have to subset within each group rather like you are doing right now (in the `i`th expression).

Could do either

```
tt1[, mean(duration[duration <= 2]), by = .(i.start, i.end)]
#    i.start i.end  V1
# 1:       3     5   2
# 2:      29    31 NaN
# 3:      20    22 NaN
# 4:      14    16   2
```

Or combine it with an `if`/`else` statement

```
tt1[, if(any(duration <= 2)) mean(duration[duration <= 2]) else NA_real_, by = .(i.start, i.end)]
#    i.start i.end V1
# 1:       3     5  2
# 2:      29    31 NA
# 3:      20    22 NA
# 4:      14    16  2
```

Another (strange) way to achieve this, is to first calculate only the means that you need and then join back with all the possible groups

```
res <- tt1[duration <= 2, mean(duration), keyby = .(i.start, i.end)]
res[unique(tt1[, .(i.start, i.end)]), on = .(i.start, i.end)]
#    i.start i.end V1
# 1:       3     5  2
# 2:      29    31 NA
# 3:      20    22 NA
# 4:      14    16  2
```

Or similarly

```
tt1[duration <= 2][unique(tt1[, .(i.start, i.end)]), on=.(i.start, i.end), 
  mean(duration), by=.EACHI]
#    i.start i.end V1
# 1:       3     5  2
# 2:      29    31 NA
# 3:      20    22 NA
# 4:      14    16  2
```